# Посмотреть текущее activity

Tags: android, activity, adb

У меня на телефоне стоит основанная на AOSP Android 11. Как я могу, подключившись по adb, узнать текущее activity в запущенном приложении? Рут, если что, есть

Comment: Что делать то будете с "текущим Activity"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep "то что нас интересует"
```

или для того же только в файл

```sh
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep "что ищем" > name_file.txt
```